# How to make a 2D collider collide only with a specific GameObject without using layers?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, physics, layer

Suppose I have a BoxCollider2D in my player GameObject and I want it to ignore all other colliders, except another BoxCollider2D within an item.

All of them are in the same layer and the layer collides with itself.

I know that there is the `Physics2D.IgnoreCollision` method, but is there a way to ignore ALL collisions except the collider of this item GameObject, that is in the same layer than the players?

Comment: Why don't you want to use layers? Is any real reason for this?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on a project that is a platform for multiple games and layers aren't allowed to be changed.

Comment: What about using triggers for that specific object? You would have to implement the colliding behavior yourself though…

Answer (score 1):

In a 2D game you can use the depth to avoid collision if you don't want to use layers. For example, you can have all the objects that are part of the collision at z=0 and all that needs to avoid collision will be at z=1. Since its a 2D game there won't be any difference in what the camera renders.

Comment: I think I'm gonna try that, although it looks like a workaround 